# what is the difference between .php and .php.inc file extension?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is .inc and why to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129842/what-is-inc-and-why-to-use-it)

what's the difference between **.php** an **.php.inc** file extension while including a php file from main php script?

```
include("filename.php");

include("filename.php.inc");
```

Comment: The difference? Looks like 4 characters. The real difference is in choosing to use include, include_once, require, or require_once.

Comment: What about Coding Standards???

Answer (score 2):

The use of .inc instead of .php dates back to the time when register_globals was enabled by default (and there were no auto globals). Since a hacker could inject any variables into the global scope, direct execution of files that are meant to be included by other could was highly dangerous. Giving these files the .inc extension was a way to forestall this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. You can call them anything you like if you're including them. Different extensions help people to understand the purpose of the files. However you should rather use filename.inc.php, otherwise if someone requests a filename.php.inc file directly they could see the source code of the file depending how your server is set up.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you can download an .inc file directly.

Comment: It may be unlikely that anyone knows about the file to call it directly, but that is just security by obscurity. A default apache install will return a .inc file as text

Comment: Yes, when the php file is so important it's a better idea not to use .inc extension.

Answer (score 0):

Both version can work but the last version is most likely not registered as an executable to the server so it's treated as a text file and can be downloaded in the worst case.

Comment: Its the server that determines what is sent to the browser. The browser wont do anything differently if sent a .php or a .inc extension

Comment: Yes, of course but without a browser you cannot watch the site and the server sends headers to the browser so the browser know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference as far as php is concerned, both files will be treated as php files.

The differences are for you (how you organise your files) **and** if both files are located in a web-accessible directory, the first one will be treated as a php file (executed) while the second one will show its source code unless you have specified that your server treats `.inc` files as php files.

Comment: Actually, your last statement is not necessarily true on Apache... Unless you have an overriding type/handler set for the `.inc` extension (which there is not by default) then both `.php` and `.php.inc` files will be treated as PHP (ie. "executed") if accessed over HTTP.

Comment: @w3d Didn't know that that is the "normal" default. It doesn't work on the server I am testing on though.

Answer (score 0):

Not much difference... The code behind both can remain same...
Just the extension is different...

What initially it started was that inc was used to include the files in plain html.. Html also has a command to include the files...
So people used to name that file filename.inc
But with php becoming popular, people started using the php based functions to include the files and the file extension changed to php because it contained mostly the php functions and classes.

But on a bigger note, not much difference between two..

**or**

Their is not much difference but some servers provide ".inc" extension as standard for includes files, ".inc" files are parsed on server side on those server. Not every server software follows or requires special configuration.