# Put an array within an array, display a drop down in php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a form using php. I am unsure how to put the country drop down menu right after the city field. I am not sure the best way to do this I have my array.

```
$labels = array (
    "first_name" => "First Name",
    "last_name" => "Last Name",
    "address" => "Address",
    "city" => "City",
    "email" => "E-mail",
    "phone" => "Phone", );

$country = array (
    "select" => "",
    "us" => "United States",
    "ca" => "Canada",
    "mx" => "Mexico", );    

$submit = "Submit";
?>
```

Here is the display code:

```
<?php
    echo "<h2>Customer Info</h2>";
echo "<form action='checkBlank.php' method='post'>";
    foreach ( $labels as $field => $label)
    {
        echo "<div class='field'>
                <label for='$field'>$label</label>
                    <input id='$field' name='$field' type='text'
                        size='42' /></div>";
        if($field == "city") {
            echo "<label for='country'>Country</label>
                    <select id='country' name='country'>";

                foreach ( $country as $select => $option)
                {
                    echo "<option value='$value'>$option</option>";
                }

            echo "</select>";
        }
    }
        echo "<div id='submit'>
            <input type='submit' value='$submit'></div>
            </form>";
?>
```

Comment: dropdowns use `<select>` and `<option>`, why the input?

Comment: input is for the field and submit button tags of the form, I haven't put the drop down tag in there yet as I am not sure where it should be put so that php will still display the $labels array while putting the select before the e-mail and phone option and after the city field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Looks like @Barmar beat me to the punch on this one but i have a similar solution

```
$labels = array (
"first_name" => "First Name",
"last_name" => "Last Name",
"address" => "Address",
"city" => "City",
"email" => "E-mail",
"phone" => "Phone", );

$country = array (
"select" => "Select One",
"us" => "United States",
"ca" => "Canada",
"mx" => "Mexico", );    

$submit = "Submit";


echo "<h2>Customer Info</h2>";
echo "<form action='checkBlank.php' method='post'>";
    foreach ( $labels as $field => $label)
    {
        echo "<div class='field'>
                <label for='$field'>$label</label>
                    <input id='$field' name='$field' type='text'
                        size='42' /></div>";
        if($field == "city") {
            echo "<label for='country'>Country</label><select id='country' name='country'>";

                foreach ( $country as $value => $option)
                {
                    echo "<option value='$value'>$option</option>";
                }

            echo "</select>";
        }
    }

    echo "<div id='submit'>
        <input type='submit' value='$submit'></div>
        </form>";
```

Comment: So I put it as i see it above, it still only lists it as a field, but will only show the mexico option and not the other 2?

Comment: That's odd, I have it working fine on my page here, do you have any other code on that page that may be interfering?

Comment: would internal css for the form effect it? other than that its exactly as you have it above

Comment: I wouldn't think so, try placing the php above in a blank file and uploading it to your web server and see if you have the same results

Comment: hmmmm, ok well it does display as a drop down when previewed locally as a .php and on the server. 

When I save it as form.inc and use the include function to display it does the displaying as a field with only mexico as an option.

Comment: Are you using .inc as part of a CMS system or is it just preference? FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129842/what-is-inc-and-why-to-use-it

Comment: Its for a school project, they require I use the .inc. I am afraid i do not yet know what a CMS system is. :/

Comment: Glad you sorted it, what was the issue?

Comment: had to restart apache and MySQL in xampp save then upload to the server

Answer (score 1):

Test the field name, and if it's the city, do another loop to display the country drop-down.

```
foreach ( $labels as $field => $label)
{
    echo "<div class='field'>
            <label for='$field'>$label</label>
                <input id='$field' name='$field' type='text'
                    size='42' /></div>";
    if ($field == 'city') {
        echo '<div><select name="country">';
        foreach ($country as $short => $long) {
            echo "<option value='$short'>$long</option>";
        }
        echo '</select></div>';
    }
}
```

BTW, it's conventional to use an empty value for the `Select One` option. Standard form validation tools will recognize this as meaning no option was selected, if you mark the field as required.

Comment: thanks barmar I have changed the select to blank and will mark the field as required

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do it like this:

```
 $fields = array (
    array(
        "name" => "first_name",
        "label" => "First Name",
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "last_name",
        "label" => "Last Name",
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "address",
        "label" => "Address",
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "city",
        "label" => "City",
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "country",
        "label" => "Country",
        "options" => array (
            "" => "Select One",
            "us" => "United States",
            "ca" => "Canada",
            "mx" => "Mexico", 
        ),  
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "email",
        "label" => "E-mail",
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "phone",
        "label" => "Phone",
    ),
);

foreach($fields as $field) {
    echo "<div class='field'><label for='{$field['name']}'>{$field['label']}</label>";
    if (isset($field['options'])) {
        echo "<select name='{$field['name']}'>";
        foreach ($option as $value => $title) {
            echo "<option value='$value'>$title</option>";
        }
        echo '</select>'
    } else {
       echo "<input id='{$field['name']}' name='{$field['name']}' type='text' size='42' />";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```