# Protected and private visibility in php

Tags: php

I have been learning PHP from an online course. I have declared protected class members. These members are not supposed to be accessible outside the class, but I'm able to access them.

This is the class (class.Address.inc.php)

```
Class Address
 {
     //Street Address
     protected $street_Address_1;
     public $street_Address_2;

     //Name of the city
     public $city_name;

     //Subdivision name
     public $subdivision_name;

     //Postal code
     public $postal_code;

     //country name
     public $country_name;
```

This is the Demo.php file in which I used the Address class.

```
<?php

require 'class.Address.inc';

     $address=new Address;
     $address->street_Address_1= "555 Fake Street";//protected but accessible
     $address->street_Address_2="Hello";
     $address->city_name="Townsville";
```

I am able to access the protected member and initialize it from Demo.php. Shouldn't protected members not be available outside the class from which it was declared?

Comment: Doesn't work for me: https://ideone.com/03ZhNl

Comment: It should throw uncaught error. what's your PHP version?

Comment: me neither http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/855f49cd25521625b711f9536541698b1865626e

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: There must be something in you REAL code that is relevant and you are not showing us!

Comment: I think in your code your class `Address` is extended from another class that share the property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but will try to take a little test again....

```
<?php

require 'class.Address.inc'; //require 'class.Address.inc.php';
$address=new Address;
$address->street_Address_1= "555 Fake Street";//protected but accessible
$address->street_Address_2="Hello";
$address->city_name="Townsville";
```

Comment: Surely if that was the actual error it would generate some other error like `Fatal error: Class 'Address' not found`

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Why did you make `require 'class.Address.inc';` bold? The question already is using that part. I see you put `require 'class.Address.inc.php';` as a comment. Are you only suggesting to add `.php` on the end? You have it reversed then.

Comment: Sorry guys it was my fault. I didnt know that .inc files were an extension of files that were to be included. If you check you will understand that I had named the file class.Address.inc.php . What I didnt realise was that I had also created a class.Address.inc file in which every member was public. I had changed the class.Address.inc.php files' member to protected . The code was accessing the class.Address.inc file and not the class.Address.inc.php. .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129842/what-is-inc-and-why-to-use-it

Answer (score 0):

how to access protected vars outside class, here you can get its value same you can do for set value.

```
<?php
class myclass{
    protected $myname;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->myname = "myclass class";
    }
}

class childclass extends myclass{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getMyName(){
        return $this->myname;
    }
}

$obj = new childclass();
echo $obj->getMyName();
```